# How to prove it strictly greater than $0$?

Tags: inequality, optimization

I'd like to prove that
$$-x \left(x^a-(x-1)^a-\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^a+\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^a\right)-(x-1)^a+\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^a+\left(1-2^{a-1}\right) \left(\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^a-\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^a\right)>0$$ 
for $x\ge 2$ and  $-1<a<0$ . 
First, I consider the closure of that domain with $-1\leq a \leq 0$. Then I try to find the minimum of this function about $x$ and $a$. I choice  Maple or Mathematica. The minimum is $0$ at $a=0$; the value of $x$ is irrelevant. And $a=0 $ is one of the boundaries.
The discussion of software is here:
*https://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/229137-Whose-Minimum-Value-Is-More-Reliable#comment266774*

Then I consider  open domain of $a$,  lower bound of  the fouction should be $0$.
So I think we get a not very strict proof.
But I want to get some theoretical support not only 
rely on Mathematics softwore. 
I'd like to get some ideas.

Comment: More of a comment than a solution: calling your function $F(x,a)$ changing your notation slightly to make $0<a<1$, playing around with things I think, but can't quite say for certain, that $a / (10x^2) < F(x,-a)$. This would immediately give $F(x,a)>0$ for $-1<a<0$.

Comment: why think of this form $a/(10x^2)$ ?

Comment: Looked at powers of $x$ and then played around with the constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality is written as $f(a, x) + g(a, x) > 0$ where
$$f(a, x) = - x^{1+a} + (x-1)^{1+a} + (x-1/2)^{1+a} - (x-3/2)^{1+a}$$
and
$$g(a, x) = (1/2 - 2^{a-1})((x-3/2)^a - (x-1/2)^a).$$

Clearly, $g(a, x) > 0$. It suffices to prove that $f(a, x) \ge 0$.
Since $x \mapsto -x^{1+a}$ is convex on $(0, \infty)$, and $(x, x - 3/2)$
majorizes $(x-1/2, x-1)$, by using
Karamata inequality, we have $f(a, x) \ge 0$. We are done.

Comment: You are amazing!  Thanks

Comment: @licheng You are welcome.